# Check if string contains embedded string in order

Tags: regex, string, bash

I want to check if some string is embedded within another string. For example `pineapple` and `apple` match as well as `aepprestlse` and `apple`.

This is a simple task if I know the word I want to test against for example:

```
if [[ $e == *"a"*"p"*"p"*"l"*"e"* ]]
then
   echo "match"
fi
```

However I do not know the length or contents of what will replace my `"apple"` variable when I run the script. How can I perform this check with variable sizes/contents?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you can generate a glob pattern to match:

```
data='bcdaeppr?estlse'
search='app?le'

# generate a regex using sed i.e. *\a*\p*\p*\?\l*\e*
patt="*$(sed 's/./\\&*/g' <<< "$search")"

# now match it
[[ $data == $patt ]] && echo "matched" || echo "nope"
matched

# not matching example
data='bcdaepprestlse'
[[ $data == $patt ]] && echo "matched" || echo "nope"
nope
```

Comment: thank you, I ended up using a dumbed down approach as I have not worked with fold before, but this got me started

Comment: you can create the same regex with `sed 's/./&.*/g;s/\.\*$//' <<< apple`

Comment: This is ok if the search string contains a restricted set of characters, but it can break in some circumstances.  Space characters in the search string are ignored.  Globbing is done on the search string characters, so weird things happen if the search string contains a `*`.  Weird things can also happen if the search string contains  regex metacharacters like `.`, `[`, and `]'.

Comment: Good points karakfa and @pjh. I have modified it now to escape glob patterns and match using globbing.

Answer (score 1):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
$ awk -v s='pineapple' -v r='apple' '
     BEGIN{for(i=1;i<=length(r);i++) 
             {s=substr(s,k); 
              k=index(s,substr(r,i,1)); 
              if(k==0) exit 1} 
           exit 0}'; echo $?
```